# codeigniter validation not working for bootstrap chosen drop down

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter for first time. i have a problem, iam using the validation as below

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {

            city:'required',
            state: 'required',
            emailid: {
                required:true,
                email: true
            },
            location: 'required',
            pincode: 'required',
            address: 'required',
            address: 'required',
            mobilenumber: {
                required:true,
                minlength:10,
                maxlength:10,
                number: true
            },

        },
        messages: {

              city: 'City Name is required',
              state: 'State Name is required',
               location: 'Location is required',
              category: 'Category is required',

               emailid: {
                required:'Email ID is required',
                email: 'Invalid Email ID'
            },
              mobilenumber: {
                required: 'Contatc Number is Required',
                minlength:'Minimum 10 digits only',
                maxlength:'Maximum 10 digits only',
                number: 'Only numeric allowed'
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Here city,state and location are bootstrap chosen drop down, for this the validation is not working. My select drop down is below

```
<select id="state" name="state" class="form-control chosen-select" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your State." onchange="getcity()">
                    <option value="0">State</option>
                    <?php 
                    foreach($allstates as $row)
                    {
                        if($state==$row->stateid){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row->stateid.'" selected>'.$row->state.'</option>';
                        }else{

                        echo '<option value="'.$row->stateid.'">'.$row->state.'</option>';

                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                                            </select>
```

This is my drop down

Comment: But you are not using codeigniter validation

Comment: yes iam using codeigniter validation

Comment: how exactly is it not working? it seems some option is selected in drop-down, so required rule passes. Am I missing sth?